# Plotly plotting in the past

Tags: javascript, plotly

When extending traces with plotly the points are drawn in the past. As you can see in the picture, any

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0UAD.png)

The chart now consists of 2 parts one on the right is data from the database, and to the left is data being plotted in "real-time". The data that is being plotted in realtime is to the left of the data from the database is even though the timestamps are after the ones from the databases.

The time stamp on the console logs is correct but plotly is placing them at the wrong time on the x-axis. The should be drawn at the end of the graph.

```
updateData (sensorData) {
    if (!this.initiated || !this.isLiveData) {
        return
    }

    let y = []
    let i = 0
    let x = []
    let traces = []
    for (let sensor in this.configuration) {
        for (let signal in this.configuration[sensor]) {
            let xDate = new Date(sensorData[sensor].timestamp)

            if (sensorData.hasOwnProperty(sensor) && sensorData[sensor].hasOwnProperty(signal)) {
                y.push([sensorData[sensor][signal]])
                x.push([xDate.getTime()])
            }
            // x time seems to be good here
            console.log('Update data', xDate.getTime(), xDate)

            traces.push(i)
            i++
        }
    }

    console.log('Plotting', y, x, this.widget.getXRange())
    if (y.length > 0) {
        this.$plotly.extendTraces('plotly-chart', {
            y: y,
            x: x
        }, traces)
    }
},
```

The data from the db is added with following code.

```
updateFromDb (sensorData) {
    let data = []
    let x = []
    let yData = {}

    for (let sensor in this.configuration) {
        for (let i = 0, len = sensorData[sensor].length; i < len; i++) {
            let timestamp = sensorData[sensor][i].timestamp
            x.push(timestamp)

            for (let source in this.configuration[sensor]) {
                let name = sensor + ' ' + getSignalName(source, this.angleLabel)

                if (!yData.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    yData[name] = {
                        data: [],
                        color: this.configuration[sensor][source].color
                    }
                }

                if (!sensorData[sensor][i].hasOwnProperty(source)) {
                    yData[name].data.push(0)
                } else {
                    yData[name].data.push(sensorData[sensor][i][source])
                }

                if (this.configuration[sensor][source].hasOwnProperty('yaxis')) {
                    yData[name]['yaxis'] = 'y' + this.configuration[sensor][source].yaxis
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (let name in yData) {
        let sensorData = {
            name: name,
            x: x,
            y: yData[name].data,
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'lines',
            line: {
                width: 2,
                color: yData[name].color
            },
            marker: {
                width: 2,
                color: yData[name].color
            }
        }

        if (yData[name].hasOwnProperty('yaxis')) {
            sensorData['yaxis'] = yData[name].yaxis
        }
        data.push(sensorData)
    }

    this.$plotly.react(
        document.getElementById('plotly-chart'),
        data,
        this.getLayout(false),
        this.chartProperties
    )
}
```

There is also a function that scroll the window over xaxis every 50 ms to make it look smooth.

```
windowScroller () {
    if (!this.initiated || !this.isLiveData) {
        return
    }

    let timeDifference = 0
    if (this.timeDifference !== null) {
        timeDifference = this.timeDifference
    }

    /**
     * Make sure the line never gets behind the scroller.
     */
    if (Object.keys(this.latestPoint).length > 0) {
        let latestTime = this.latestPoint[Object.keys(this.latestPoint)[0]].timestamp
        let scrollDiff = new Date().getTime() - latestTime
        if (scrollDiff !== this.scrollDelay && this.lastDelayTime !== latestTime && scrollDiff < 60000) {
            this.lastDelayTime = latestTime
            this.scrollDelay = scrollDiff
            // console.log('update scroll', scrollDiff, 'from', latestTime)
        }
    }

    let currentTime = new Date().getTime() - timeDifference - this.scrollDelay
    let firstTime = new Date().getTime() - this.getMilisecondsFromMinutes(this.widget.getXRange()) - timeDifference - this.scrollDelay
    let relayoutPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.$plotly.relayout('plotly-chart', {
            xaxis: {
                color: '#fff',
                type: 'date',
                range: [firstTime, currentTime]
            }
        })
    })

    relayoutPromise.then(() => {
        console.log('relayout')
    })

    let data = document.getElementById('plotly-chart').data

    // We calculate the max points using 4 hertz
    let maxPoints = (this.getSecondsFromMinutes(this.widget.getXRange()) + 10) * this.widget.getRefreshRate()

    if (this.minMax) {
        maxPoints = maxPoints * 2
    }
    for (let i in data) {
        if (data[i].y.length >= maxPoints) {
            data[i].y.shift()
            data[i].x.shift()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code above is responsible for plotting only the real-time data, correct? Could you also provide the code which plots the database data?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Thank you for taking interest in the post. I have updated the post with some more information.